# Problems receiving a POSTed XML file in PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I want to upload a smal xml file to my website and I use a small piece of C# code to accomplish that. However, the procedure on the receiving site appears to be a problem. I can not run a ASP.NET controller function because the provider does not support it. They do support PHP and Perl. I tried both (being very bad in Perl). But calling a PHP procedure gives me always - even with an empty procedure the message: "End of script output before headers: FileUpload.php" (500 error on Apache). No matter what I do in the script, this is the message. Perl does the same. At some point I called Header() as the only call but that gave the same result.

So my question is: is it technically possible to use the C# code as below with a PHP on the receiving side? Or does it always have to be a matching technique (PHP sending and receiving, .NET sending/receiving etc...). Currently I am lost. What do I do wrong? How to accomplish?

C# code to send the file:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) 
{
   string requestname = "https://domain.nl/" + "receivingRecource";
   client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "file/xml");
   response = client.UploadFile(requestname, "POST", localfile);
   Console.WriteLine($"ResponseHeaders for Upload\n{client.ResponseHeaders.ToString()}"); 
}
Console.WriteLine($"\nFileUpload Response: {Encoding.ASCII.GetString( response )}");
```

The receiving side had - par example - the following error 500 generating code (Note that there won't be any user interaction, the form code is just to get something. I will remove that when I get it working):

````
   if(isset($_FILES['file'])){
      $errors= array();
      $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
      $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
      $file_tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
      $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
      $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['file']['name'])));

      $extensions= array("xml");

      if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions)=== false){
         $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose XML.";
      }

      if($file_size > 2097152) {
         $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
      }

      if(empty($errors)==true) {
         move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);
         echo "Success";
      }else{
         print_r($errors);
      }
   }
?>
<html>
   <body>

      <form action = "" method = "POST" enctype = "text/xml">
         <input type = "file" name = "file" />
         <input type = "submit"/>

         <ul>
            <li>Sent file: <?php echo $_FILES['file']['name'];  ?>
            <li>File size: <?php echo $_FILES['file']['size'];  ?>
            <li>File type: <?php echo $_FILES['file']['type'] ?>
         </ul>

      </form>

   </body>
</html>```
````

Comment: A 500 response is returned when the program throws an error instead of producing a response. While I don't know PHP, this should result in an error in the web server's error log. What error did you get?

Comment: I got the error in the log file: "End of script output before headers: FileUpload.php" (which is the 500 error)